# Stored Procedure Performance Issue 1.5 Million Records in Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, query-performance

I have scenario where I am executing the following query inside a stored procedure as part of a sql agent job and it takes hours to complete the execution. Can anyone suggest a better approach for rewriting this query? The `#ownership` table has 1.5 million records.

```
WHILE (@last_update > 0)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #ownership
     SELECT DISTINCT
        a.ParentNumber,
         b.ChildNumber
     FROM #ownership a,
     #ownership b
     WHERE a.ChildNumber = b.ParentNumber
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM #ownership c
                  WHERE c.ParentNumber = a.ParentNumber
                    AND c.ChildNumber  = b.ChildNumber)
     SET @last_update = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Comment: Consider also posting at https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: When @last_update <= 0?

Comment: Maybe remove the distinct and see how long it takes and look at the results.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s that `Bad habits` link is not working

Comment: @Squirrel: thanks - updated: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Does this query actually do anything?   What is some sample data you have before the query, and after?

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing you can do for the performance of this code is to INDEX `#ownership` on `ParentNumber, ChildNumber`.